# How to categorize objects associated with ForeignKey Django

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I have two model classes

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and

```
class Site(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

So in the templates, I wanted to categorize (put together) sites with the same category together. As in there will be links with all categories on the home page

```
            {% for category in category_list %}
            <li><a href="">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
```

and when you click the link for a category, the sites with the same categories appear. How do I do that?

Comment: This part is confusing: "So in the templates, I wanted to categorize (put together) sites with the same category together. As in there will be links with all categories on the home page." What does the second sentence have to do with the first? Do you want two different templates, one with the former sentence's behavior, and another for the homepage?

Comment: Sorry It was confusing. Yeah 2 templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

class SiteView(ListView):
    template_name = 'site.html'
    context_object_name = 'site_list'
    paginate_by = 8

    def get_category(self):
        category_id = self.request.GET.get('category', '')
        if category_id:
            try:
                category = Category.objects.get(id=category_id)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                category = None
        else:
            category = None
        return category

    def get_queryset(self):
        category = self.get_category()
        if category:
            return Site.objects.filter(category=category).all()
        else:
            return Site.objects.all()
```

urls.py

```
   url(r'^site/$', SiteView.as_view(), name='site'),
```

templates

```
        {% for category in category_list %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'site' %}?category={{ category.id }}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404, get_object_or_404

def category_view(request):
    category_list = get_list_or_404(Category)
    context = {'category_list': category_list}
    return render(request, '-your_templates-/category.html', context)

def site_view(request, cat_id):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=cat_id)
    context = {'category': category}
    return render(request, '-your_templates-/site.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^category/$', views.category_view, name='category'), 
url(r'^category/(?P<cat_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.site_view, name='site'),
```

category.html

```
{% for category in category_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'app_name:site' category.id %}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

I hope this helps.